# John the Ripper known part of password

Tags: john-the-ripper

For migration purposes i need to get the plaintext password for all our accounts, stored in the shadow file.

Our system uses usernames in the format "`firstname.lastname`" and password is either "`firstname + single_number + single_letter`" or "`lastname + single_number + single_letter`", like "`firstname3p`" or "`lastname3p`"

What is the correct way to use filters to extract firstname or lastname and try every combination of number + letter on them?

Comment: The correct way would be to use this opportunity to stop using easily guessable passwords.

Comment: This is more of a programming question than a security question.

Comment: May I use this as an example of "How **NOT** to do things"?

Comment: Exactly. It's a legacy system and i am changing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion the best way to do that is creating a wordlist with all the possibilities using a script for example and then using that wordlist in John the Ripper